# Why this problem is NP-Hard?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, np

I'm asking about the question described here:
[Knapsack Problem with exact required item number constraint](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/123553/knapsack-problem-with-exact-required-item-number-constraint)

Can't we iterate over $\binom{n}{L}$ options (which is polynomial), and for each option check if the constraints are met?

Answer (score 2):

$L$ is given as part of the input, and can be e.g., $n/2$, where $n$ is the number of items.
Then, iterating over ${n\choose L}={n\choose \frac{n}2}$ is exponential.

Note that it doesn't matter whether $L$ is given in unary or binary, since $n$ is given in unary (as a list of the different items).

Comment: But as the author has written - L is given as a constant.

Comment: The reduction in the answer takes $L$ to be part of the input. If $L$ is an absolute constant, then yes - you can certainly iterate over ${n\choose L}$.