# Knapsack Problem with exact required item number constraint with no values

Tags: algorithms, knapsack-problems

Similar to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/123553/knapsack-problem-with-exact-required-item-number-constraint) but items don't have value $v$.

Max weight $W$, every item has weight $w$, must add *exactly* $L$ items to the knapsack, need to get max weight as possible.

Comment: Take the value of the item as the weight of the item. Then, it is the same problem.

Comment: You are right. What does $n(V+1)$ mean in that answer?

Comment: I have added another answer to the question (probably simpler), you can check that.